# Can't insert the record to database C# SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, sqlite

I've been struggling with an error related to the database. Basically I have an SQLite db and I want to insert the data, but after I execute the method, no data is written to the db but no errors are shown either. This is my code:
The db connection class:

```
class SqlDb
    {
        public static SQLiteConnection SqLiteConnection;
        public static string DATABASE_WAREHOUSE = "DaneDB.db";

        public static string DATABASE_LACZKA =
            $"Data Source= {DATABASE_WAREHOUSE};Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";

        public SQLiteConnection Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                SqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(DATABASE_LACZKA);
                SqLiteConnection.Open();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Could not connect to the database {e}");
                throw;
            }

            return SqLiteConnection;
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            SqLiteConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

and the inserting method

```
private void LoadToDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Data modelData = new Data();
            SqlDb db = new SqlDb();
            SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection = db.Connect();
            SQLiteCommand sqLiteCommand = sqLiteConnection.CreateCommand();


            try
            {
                modelData.Name = firstName.Text;
                modelData.Age = Convert.ToInt32(DisplayAge.Text);
                modelData.LastName = LastName.Text;

                sqLiteCommand.CommandText =
                    $"insert into DANE values('{modelData.Name}', '{modelData.LastName}', '{modelData.Age}')"; 

                    db.Disconnect();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

I also have the options of database set to:

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to output directory: Copy always
```

Comment: That is a very dangerous and very, very error prone way to concoct SQL queries.  Use SQL Parameters always.  Your connections also ought to be disposed of when you are done with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to execute this command:

```
sqLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please refer to documentation: [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executenonquery?view=msdata-sqlite-5.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteCommand_ExecuteNonQuery)